# how can we use multiple variables in single for loop in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, for

I am implementing as below code using for loop but wrong output coming after running the script.

```
for i in `awk -F"|" '{print $1}' $INPUTFILE`, j in `awk -F"|" '{print $2}' $INPUTFILE`
do
echo $i:$j
done
```

Please help me to use multiple variables in single for loop in shell script.

Comment: Possibly related: [Passing multiple parameters via xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387076/80216). See in particular [Stéphane Chazelas’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387076/80216#444784).

Answer (score 25):

bash allows for loops with more than one variable, but only in C like syntax:

```
for ((i=0,j=10;i<=j;i++,j--))
do
   echo "i=$i"
   echo "j=$j"
done
```

Comment: how are i and j read from $INPUTFILE ?

Comment: @Archemar They're not. The question, I believe, is wrong. Using for loops on awk is usually wrong as you can usually accomplish whatever you wanted in pure awk, and see Stéphane Chazelas's answer. I just answered the question in the title.

Answer (score 24):

Maybe you actually want:

```
while IFS='|' read -r i j rest <&3; do
  {
    printf '%s\n' "something with $i and $j"
  } 3<&-
done 3< "$INPUTFILE"
```

But [using a shell loop to process text is often the wrong way to go](/q/169716).

Here, it sounds like you just need:

```
awk -F '|' '{print $1 ":" $2}' < "$INPUTFILE"
```

Now as an answer to the question in the title, for a shell with `for` loops taking more than one variable, you've got `zsh` (you seem to already be using zsh syntax by not quoting your variables or not disabling globbing when splitting command substitution):

```
$ for i j in {1..6}; do echo $i:$j; done
1:2
3:4
5:6
```

Or the shorter form:

```
for i j ({1..6}) echo $i:$j
```

The equivalent with POSIX shells:

```
set -- 1 2 3 4 5 6
## or:
# IFS='
# ' # split on newline
# set -o noglob # disable globbing
# set -- $(awk ...) # split the output of awk or other command
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  printf '%s\n' "$1:$2"
  shift 2
done
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using a new fd (`<&3`) and what does `-` after that do? Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @sdkks, you can use any fd you like (between 0 and 9, some shells allowing more, some even allowing allocating them dynamically), but it's better to avoid 0, 1 and 2 as those are special. That's stdin, stdout and stderr and the commands inside the loop may need to use them (in the case of `printf` only 1 and possibly 2 for errors). `3<&-` is the syntax to close a fd. We're closing 3 for the commands inside the loop as they don't need access to (and shouldn't use) that resource.

Answer (score 6):

You can store an output of a file in a variable and then break it into two. example:

in **example** file contents are:

```
a:1
b:2
c:3
d:4
```

now script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in $(cat example)
do
    first=$(echo $n | cut -d ":" -f 1)
    second=$(echo $n | cut -d ":" -f 2)
    echo $first
    echo $second
done
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ cat inputfile.txt
foo|bar
baz|foobar
$ cat inputfile.txt | while IFS='|' read i j ; do echo $i:$j ; done
foo:bar
baz:foobar
```

this answer is a lot like [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279764/409299) but it also answers the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279760/how-can-we-use-multiple-variables-in-single-for-loop-in-shell-script/279764#comment681973_279764) about not having to use file descriptors (`<&3`) by @sdkks

Comment: I needed to iterate over input from another process, receiving lines over the network, and I'm not sure how to attach a process to a file descriptor, so this was helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

On embedded systems, you are often crippled on what is available.  EG. `for` can only have one variable; `awk` & `printf` are simply not available; or `IFS` is not supported; etc.

In these circumstances you can achieve your goal like this:

```
export i=xxx
for j in `cat INPUTFILE` ; do \
    [ $i == xxx ] && export i=$j && continue ; \
    echo "$i:$j" ; \
    export i=xxx ; \
done
unset i
```

A more general form of this solution might look like:

```
export A=xxx
export B=xxx
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ; do \
    [ $A == xxx ] && export A=$i && continue ; \
    [ $B == xxx ] && export B=$i && continue ; \
    echo "$A:$B:$i" ; \
    export A=xxx ; \
    export B=xxx ; \
done
unset A
unset B
```

- Assumes the string "xxx" never appears in your data-set ...If it does/might, pick something else.
- You can have any number of "fields" per "record" ...Just duplicate each of the FOUR lines which handle the fields {A, B, ...}.
- The last field is always called $i ...Feel free to add an `export C=$i` just before the `echo` if it helps.
- If the number of strings in the data-set is not a multiple of the record-size, the "remainder" (ie. |set| % |record|) will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel can often be a solution for this:

```
parallel -a $INPUTFILE --colsep '|' echo {1}:{2}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used as a one-liner inside the bash shell to iterate over two sets of variables in parallel (as `zip(a, b)` would do in python):

```
a=(x y z); b=(q w e); for i in ${!a[@]}; do echo ${a[i]}-${b[i]}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need multiple loops if you want to iterate over more than one variable, like `for i in 1 2 3; do for j in a b c; do ...; done; done`. when the list of things to iterate over is the output of a another command, you'll need to wrap that other command in `$()`.

Comment: I am not sure OP want a cross product, more likely OP want i,j from first line of $INPUTFILE, then i,j from second line and so on.

Comment: I opted for not trying to parse the awk parts of the question, but after re-reading it, I think you're right an that Stephane's answer is right on.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

num="num.txt"
ch="char.txt"
int1=0

for i in `cat $num`
do
 int1=$(( $int1+1 ))

 for j in `cat $ch|tail -n +$int1`
 do
  echo $i " " $j
 break
 done

done
```

Output:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
```

Comment: Note that the user in the question has a single input file with two `|`-delimited fields and that they try to output the two fields with a `:` in-between them.