# Passing multiple parameters via xargs

Tags: xargs

I'd like to be able to use `xargs` to execute multiple parameters in different parts of a command.

For example, the following:

```
echo {1..8} | xargs -n2 | xargs -I v1 -I v2 echo the number v1 comes before v2
```

I would hope that it would return

```
the number 1 comes before 2
the number 3 comes before 4
```

... etc

Is this achievable? I suspect that my multiple use of `-I` is incorrect.

Comment: I believe this is why you can't use `-I` this way: according to the `man page`, `-I` implies `-n 1`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I believe that you can’t use `-I` that way. 
But you can get the effect / behavior you want by saying:

```
echo {1..8} | xargs -n2 sh -c 'echo "the number $1 comes before $2"' sh
```

This, essentially, creates an *ad hoc* one-line shell script,
which `xargs` executes via `sh -c`. 
The two values that `xargs` parses out of the input
are passed to this “script”. 
The shell then assigns those values to `$1` and `$2`,
which you can then reference in the “script”.

Comment: Thank you - that's great. I've been reading the man for sh though and am struggling understanding what the second call to sh does and, by  extension, why its omission yields 'half' the result.

Comment: @DamienSawyer There is no second call to `sh`.  The trailing `sh` at the end is what is put into `$0`.  `$0` is usually what holds the name of the interpreter or the script.

Comment: I just replaced trailing `sh` with `echo $sh` which it works. So final `sh` functions as a placeholder

Comment: Well, that’s an oversimplification of what Kusalananda said.

Comment: I didn't get the explanation about trailing `sh` but running `xargs --verbose` made it clearer: the trailing value passed is fed into `sh -c` execution as `$0` env variable. So if your script doesn't use `$0`, you can pass whatever. It's just customary to pass `sh`. And it's needed so that xargs can output the other params (you need `$0` first to output `$1`, `$2`...  replacements). Example: `sh -c 'echo $1/$2/$0' sh A B` writes `A/B/sh` (more about `$0`:  https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$0)

Comment: It doesn't work in a script and if you want to use double quotes to have access to variables defined before in the script because $0..$N are interpreted as script parameters. For instance `echo "bar" | xargs -n 1 sh -c "echo \"${FOO}: $0\"" `

Comment: @Scott why in your answer xargs does not need to end with `\;`?

Comment: @Porcupine: `xargs` commands never need to end with `\;`.

Comment: @Scott When xargs is used with find and bash shell is invoked in xargs pipe. It ends with `\;`. Could you please tell why is it needed here but not in your answer?

Comment: @Porcupine: Your question contains its own answer. The arguments to the `-exec` action of `find` end with `\;` (or `+`) — and my answer doesn’t use `find`. Bash doesn’t really have anything to do with it; in principle, you can run `xargs` and/or `find` without using a shell. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Those of us who come here and answer questions do so because we want to help people. But we prefer not to deal with questions that could easily be answered by looking at documentation.

Comment: After all this discussion, I'm here to praise such a beautiful answer. I'm pretty sure that I will use this one killer command for everything. Thx, stackexchange community. I would like not to have my compliments erased by some moderator, but I was feeling the urge to compliment everyone here. <3

Answer (score 8):

In the specific case of `printf`, you could always do:

```
echo {1..8} | xargs printf 'the number %s comes before %s\n'
```

because `printf` has an intrinsic `xargs`-like ability to execute multiple times
if it is given more arguments than it needs for a single invocation. 
Though that has little advantage over

```
printf 'the number %s comes before %s\n' {1..8}
```

And for large lists, the simple `xargs` command could result
in `xargs` running several instances of `printf`,
some of which might have odd numbers of arguments.
You could pass `-n 1000` to `xargs` to guard against that, where 1000 is an even number that should be small enough so as not to reach the *arg list too long* limit and large enough to avoid running so many `printf`s.

Note that `xargs` would call, not your shell's builtin `printf`,
but the external `printf`, with each invocation in a separate new process.

Also note that for an empty input, except on some BSDs, it would still run `printf` once with no argument. GNU `xargs` and compatible have a `-r`
(or `--no-run-if-empty`) option to avoid that.

To be clear, this simple answer is specific to your `printf` example,
and would not work in the general case
where you must pass two parameters at a time to your command
(as would be the case for `diff`, for example). 
To solve the general problem with `zsh`, you can use:

```
for i j ({1..8}) echo "the number $i comes before $j"
```

Comment: (1) IMHO, the `zsh` part of the above is a real answer, and the `xargs`-with-no-options part is just an oddity.  In such a case, I would consider putting the real answer first.  (2) I assume you have a reason for *not* using quotes in your ```zsh``` command.  If so, you might want to state it, lest people read the above and start to think that quotes aren’t important.  (Or simply include them, since they don’t hurt.)

Comment: This is really cool. I landed here looking for something similar where I wasn't sure ahead of time how many args I was going to receive that had to be put into the command line of the next arg. did something like `awk -F'\t' '/match/{printf $1"\0"$2"\0"}' | xargs -0 printf -- '-args1 "%s" -args2 "%s"' | xargs mycommand`

Comment: @keithpjolley, your usage of `-0` on the first `xargs` to make it more reliable is defeated by you not using it on the second. Also, the first argument to `printf` (both the standalone utility and `awk`'s `printf()` function) is the format, you shouldn't use variables there. Here, you could do `awk -F'\t' '/match/{printf "-args1\0%s\0-args2\0%s\0", $1, $2}' | xargs -n400 -r0 mycommand`. Again, `-n400` needed to ensure `xargs` passes a number of arguments that is a multiple of 4. (note that not all `awk` implementations support using `\0` like that here).

Comment: didn't use `-0` to make it more reliable, used it to have it do what i wanted to do, which it does.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
echo {1..8} |xargs -n 2 bash -c 'echo "the number $0 comes before $1"'
```

Comment: This would work in this case, but it's better to run `sh -c` script with `sh` (or whatever) in `$0`.  Note that `$0` is not included in `$@` if this was to be used by the `sh -c` script, for example if the script was `echo "the two numbers were $@"`