# GNU Parallel doesn't run the jobs until the program has exited

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zsh, xargs, gnu-parallel

When I run (rss-notifier's code is included at the end),

```
rss-notifier.zsh https://www.wuxiaworld.com/feed/chapters ".*"|parallel --null -k --lb echo {}
```

I get,

```
Title: Sovereign of the Three Realms - Chapter 1339: Tears Of Joy
Link: https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/sovereign-of-the-three-realms/sotr-chapter-1339

Title: Renegade Immortal - Chapter 1259 - Rebuking the Everlasting Sect, Flowing Time
Link: https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/renegade-immortal/rge-chapter-1259

Title: Condemning the Heavens - Chapter 242: Three-eyed Troublemaker
Link: https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/condeming-the-heavens/cth-chapter-242

Title: Condemning the Heavens - Chapter 241: Join Us
Link: https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/condeming-the-heavens/cth-chapter-241
```

But when I run,

```
rss-notifier.zsh https://www.wuxiaworld.com/feed/chapters ".*"|parallel --null -k --lb -N 2 echo {1} {2}
```

I get nothing because parallel waits for the program to exit first.

How can I solve this problem? I just want parallel to execute my `command {1} ... {2}` for each two null-separated strings it reads from stdin.

Here is rss-notifier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
rsstail -l -u "$1" -n 9 | while read -r line1
do
    read -r line2
    if ggrep -P --silent "$2" <<< "$line1" ; then
        printf '%b' "$line1"'\0'"$line2"'\0'
        echo
    fi
done
```

Or for a simpler reproducer:

```
(printf '%s\0' {1..4}; sleep 2) | parallel --null -k --lb -N 2 echo {1} {2}
```

Update: I would also be satisfied by any alternative utility that can accomplish my use case. Here is how to do it with xargs, but it is not very graceful:

[Passing multiple parameters via xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387076/passing-multiple-parameters-via-xargs)

Answer (score 1):

You are being hit by two issues.

This

```
(seq 200; sleep 20) | parallel -j10  -k echo
```

prints:

```
1
2
```

and then stalls until the `sleep 20` is done.

A partial fix seems to be to move `start_more_jobs()` outside the `while` loop:

```
--- a/src/parallel
+++ b/src/parallel
@@ -4062,9 +4062,8 @@ sub reaper {
        # $stiff = pid of dead process
        if(wantarray) {
            push(@pids_reaped,$stiff);
-       } else {
-           $children_reaped++;
        }
+       $children_reaped++;
         if($Global::sshmaster{$stiff}) {
             # This is one of the ssh -M: ignore
             next;
@@ -4112,12 +4111,12 @@ sub reaper {
             }
         }
        $job->cleanup();
-       start_more_jobs();
        if($opt::progress) {
            my %progress = progress();
            ::status_no_nl("\r",$progress{'status'});
        }
     }
+    if($children_reaped) { start_more_jobs(); }
     $opt::sqlmaster and $Global::sql->run("COMMIT;");
     debug("run", "done ");
     return wantarray ? @pids_reaped : $children_reaped;
```

This may cost some performance if you have many short lived jobs. I have not measured how much.

The other part of the problem is due to a design decision in GNU Parallel.

Arguments in GNU Parallel are read using the diamond operator (<>). This reads a full line before continuing. Reading from `(sleep 20)` only generates an end-of-file after `sleep` finishes, and thus blocks until `sleep` finishes.

So when GNU Parallel reads the final byte, it has to wait for the `sleep` to finish to discover that this indeed is the end-of-file.

I see no easy way to change that part of the design.

Luckily this does not block the jobs from being run as you can see if you run `date`. The jobs are started immediately, it is just the output that is waiting for the `sleep`:

```
(seq 20; sleep 5) | parallel -j10  -k 'date;echo'
```

In other words: Your problem is not related to `-N2`. You can not see the problem here:

```
(printf '%s\0' {1..4}; sleep 2) | parallel --null -k --lb -N 2 echo {1} {2}
```

But you *can* see the problem here. This pauses before the last 4-8 elements:

```
(printf '%s\0' {1..40}; sleep 2) | parallel -j4 --null -k --lb -N 2 echo {1} {2}
```

This pauses before the last 8-10 elements:

```
(printf '%s\0' {1..40}; sleep 2) | parallel -j8 --null -k --lb -N 2 echo {1} {2}
```

By running `date` you can see the problem is not the starting of the jobs - it is only postponing the printing:

```
(printf '%s\0' {1..40}; sleep 2) | parallel -j4 --null -k --lb -N 2 'date;'echo {1} {2}
```

Comment: I don’t understand how these issues relate to the behavior change I described in the question (“-N 2”). The second problem also doesn’t seem to be the case for my problem, since I’m echoing useless newlines in rss-notifier. Thanks for your efforts, though. :)