# xargs combined with bash -c with multiple placeholders

Tags: bash, pipe, ls, xargs

I am combining `ls`, `xargs` and `bash -c` to run a specific program on multiple input files (whose names match the pattern `barcode0[1-4].fastq`.

The program that I am calling with `xargs` is called [krocus](https://github.com/andrewjpage/krocus) and below is the code I used to call the program with a single placeholder (for the multiple input files):

```
ls barcode0[1-4].fastq |cut -d '.' -f 1|xargs -I {} bash -c "krocus --verbose --output_file out_krocus/{}_Ecoli1.txt /nexusb/Gridion/MLST_krocus_DBs/e_coli1 {}.fastq
```

In the above code my placeholder are the files I want to call krocus on i.e. `barcode0[1-4].fastq`. I now want to add a second placeholder that will be passed to the `--kmer` argument of krocus. For this argument, I want to pass the numbers `seq 12 14` i.e. 12, 13 and 14. In this example I would like to create a total of 12 files (which means I want to combine the three `--kmer` values for the four input files)

Below is how I imagine this code would look like with the placeholder for the `kmer` argument:

```
ls barcode0[1-4].fastq |cut -d '.' -f 1|xargs -I {} bash -c "krocus --verbose --output_file out_krocus/{placeholderForInputFile}_{placeholderForKmerSize}Ecoli1.txt /nexusb/Gridion/MLST_krocus_DBs/e_coli1 --kmer {placeholderForKmerSize} {placeholderForInputFile}.fastq
```

The problem is that I need to pipe the output of two commands i.e. `ls barcode0[1-4].fastq` and `seq 12 14`

Comment: does this helps? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387076/72456

Comment: I had a look at that post. The difference is that on that post he's piping from a single command (`echo {1..8`) whereas I need to pipe from two commands (`ls barcode0[1-4].fastq` and `seq 12 14`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Don't Parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)
2. `xargs` does not support two placeholders.
3. Use a for loop.  Actually, two loops (one for the filenames, and one for the 12..14 sequence).

   For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for f in barcode0[1-4].fastq; do
  bn="$(basename "$f" .fastq)"
  for k in {12..14}; do
    krocus --verbose --output_file "out_krocus/${bn}_${k}Ecoli1.txt" \
      /nexusb/Gridion/MLST_krocus_DBs/e_coli1 --kmer "$k" "$f"
  done
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing a python script, which does the same as your `.sh` script

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel krocus --verbose --output_file out_krocus/{1.}_{2}Ecoli1.txt /nexusb/Gridion/MLST_krocus_DBs/e_coli1 --kmer {2} {1} ::: barcode0[1-4].fastq ::: {12..14}
```