# Using comma delimited data as separate arguments to command

Tags: bash, cut

I am using `xargs` in conjunction with `cut`, but I am unsure how to get the output of `cut` to a variable that I can pipe to use for further processing.

So, I have a text file like so:

`test.txt`:

```
/some/path/to/dir,filename.jpg
/some/path/to/dir2,filename2.jpg
...
```

I do this:

```bsh
cat test.txt | xargs -L1 | cut -d, -f 1,2
/some/path/to/dir,filename.jpg
```

but what Id like to do is:

```bsh
cat test.txt | xargs -L1 | cut -d, -f 1,2 | echo $1 $2
```

where `$1` and `$2` are `/some/path/to/dir` and `filename.jpg`.

I am stumped that I cannot seem to able to achieve this.

What I want to achieve is:

```bsh
read_somehow_the text_fields_from text_file |  ./mypgm -i $1 -o $2
```

Comment: `xargs -L1` is not really doing anything for you here since `cut` operates line-by-line anyway. How about something like `while IFS=, read x y; do echo "\$x is $x and \$y is $y"; done < test.txt` instead?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

To split fields by spaces instead of commas can be done by `tr`, or just the simple `cut -f1,2 -d, --output-delimiter ' ' file` will be sufficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing multiple parameters via xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387076/passing-multiple-parameters-via-xargs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `parallel` has more options than `xargs` for reading columnar data; you could use

```
$ parallel --colsep , echo ./mypgm -i {1} -o {2} :::: test.txt
./mypgm -i /some/path/to/dir -o filename.jpg
./mypgm -i /some/path/to/dir2 -o filename2.jpg
```

Alternatively, using a shell loop:

```
$ while IFS=, read -r x y rest_if_any_ignored; do echo ./mypgm -i "$x" -o "$y"; done < test.txt
./mypgm -i /some/path/to/dir -o filename.jpg
./mypgm -i /some/path/to/dir2 -o filename2.jpg
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: very interesting - because I was originally running parallel wih two max jobs using the --jobs param and I assumed using one job with parallel is impossible. thank you for the soluruon!